# Is global objects (e.g. Array) are part of Javascript programming Language?

Tags: javascript, global-object

I read  the ECMAScript Doc and MDN Documents

In browser or node environment, Javascript provides some global objects like `Array` and they have functions like `filter` and `map`.

The question is: are these objects/functions part of the "Javascript Language" or are there just provided by the "environment"?

Comment: the answer is right in the title of the ECMAScript document.

Comment: Javascript interpreter itself is provided by "environment"

Comment: Partly. `Array, Object, Map, Set, Number, String, Boolean, Math` (you can find them somewhere in the *global objects * section) are, the rest is not

Comment: You say you read the ECMAScript spec. Well, everything in it is, by definition, the JavaScript language. Everything else (like browser or Node APIs) is, by the same definition, *not* part of the language. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Functions like `filter` and `map` are described in standards. This means that all browsers that follow those standards should implement them in the same way, making them act the same way, without exception.

For example, for `filter`, there is this page: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which explains the function, and at the bottom you can see links to the [document](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20) which explains exactly how the function should behave, what parameters it should have, what it should return, etc.

Comment: This is all true, but no answer to the question. The DOM is standard but not part of the JavaScript language.